# No default constructor available when I put a struct in an union, but no errors if it is outside

Tags: c++

I am trying to put RenderTargetView into an union defined below.

But when I try to do that I get the error for the no default constructor available. I am sure there should be default constructor because everything is defined.

Also if I put RenderTargetView outside of the union I am no longer getting that error. Does anyone know what is happening here ?

Eroror message:

> GP::Private::ResourceView::ResourceView(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
> Function was implicitly deleted because 'GP::Private::ResourceView' has a variant data member 'GP::Private::ResourceView::RTView' with a non-trivial default constructor

```
struct RenderTargetView
{
    static constexpr uint32_t INVALID_INDEX = static_cast<uint32_t>(-1);
    uint32_t Index = INVALID_INDEX;
};

struct FailingStruct
{
    union
    {
        RenderTargetView RTView;
    };
};
```

Comment: What's the default value of `Format`?

Comment: It is an enum, so whatever is 0.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: There are several types referenced in that code, and no information about them.   If *any* of the union members is not default-constructible, the whole union isn't.   Some compilers will diagnose such cases with messages that spuriously refer to the wrong union member (presumably because they parse more code before detecting the error).

Comment: @Peter no it is for sure RenderTargetView, because without it everything works. Most of the types are C style structs, so very basic.

Comment: @MarkoSreckovic  Then you need to apply some effort to produce a [mcve].   When there is a lot of stuff in your code that isn't described (types in your case) then people trying to help are forced to guess what relevant information you have omitted.  It's obvious you have left out stuff that YOU think is irrelevant, but that doesn't mean it is irrelevant.     Also, that doesn't mean provide all the type definitions - it means cut down your example so it doesn't rely on additional types unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I've updated the code, it appears that assigning static constexpr to a member is a issue, still not sure why. I've tried to assign Index in constructor but same error. If I put it outside of the union it compiles.

Comment: Can't reproduce, unfortunately.  With gcc on my current machine, I get no diagnostics.

Comment: Does the error appear, if the union has only the member `RTView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union has default non deleted constructor only if all members of the union have trivial constructors. Same for destructors. Since your struct has a member initializer this means that it doesn't have a trivial constructor this means the union constructor is deleted. You need to create special members for union where you delegate to the active member.

Or better yet use `std:: variant` which has all this created for you.

As for why it's simple: a union doesn't know which member is active so it cannot call the appropriate constructor/destructor.

Comment: Yeah this was the problem. Didn't know about the variant type, I will try to use it.